# How does one query a SQL View with Linq to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-view

I normally do something like this...

```
var theDogs = from d in db.Dogs where d.Equals(5) select d;

//LetThemOut(theDogs);
```

where db is the DataContext and Dogs is a table, but what about a View?

Is it the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. You just can't insert/update/delete data in a view.

If you're using the LINQ to SQL designer, just drag the view to the DBML designer.

If you're using a manual mapping, just map the object you are defining to a view, instead of a table.

Comment: oh Duh, I forgot about the designer entirely /facepalm